# If $Q$ is a radical ideal of $R$ with $Q∩S=∅$, then $QR_S$ is a radical ideal of $R_S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, localization

If $Q$ is a radical ideal of $R$ with $Q∩S=∅$, show $QR_S$ is a radical ideal of $R_S$.

Here is what I have done, since $Q$ is radical, let $q\in Q$ , then $q^n\in I$ for some $I$ ideal.
let $a\in QR_S$, then $a=q\cdot r/s$ for some $q\in Q$, $r\in R$ and $s\in S$.
then $a^n=q^n\cdot r^n/s^n\in IR_S$. since $IR_S$ is a ideal of $R_S$. we are done.

Am I right? and what I have confuse is why we need the condition of $Q∩S=∅$? I didn't use it at all. please help, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but what you have done doesn't make much sense to me. Radical ideals are those where you can obtain $q \in I$ from $q^n \in I$, not the other way round.

Comment: I think it is easier to use the fact that radical ideals are equal to the intersection of all prime ideals containing them.

Answer (score 2):

$Q$ is a radical ideal if $\forall x\in R$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^n\in Q$ it follows that $x\in Q$.
The condition for $Q\cap S=\emptyset$, assuming $S$ is a multiplicatively closed system has to be required for all ideals $P$ for which you construct $PR_S$ (as not to be equal to the whole ring) which can be proved to be an ideal of $R_S$. Otherwise, assume $\exists x\in Q\cap S\Rightarrow x\cdot 1/x\in QR_S\Rightarrow 1\in QR_S\Rightarrow QR_S=R_S$.
Now for the radical part, take $q\in R_S$, $q=a/s$, $a\in R$, $s\in S$ such that $\exists n\in\mathbb N$ such that $q^n\in QR_S\Rightarrow a^n/s^n=b/t, b\in Q, t\in S\Rightarrow  a^nt=bs^n\in Q\Rightarrow b^ns^n\in Q\Rightarrow a^nt\in Q\Rightarrow $

$a^nt^n\in Q\Rightarrow$ since $Q$ radical, $at\in Q\Rightarrow at/st=a/s\in QR_S$.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but can you add in some steps for $a^n \in Q$ ? I'm not seeing why this follows...

Comment: @darijgrinberg Sorry, my mistake I fixed it.

Comment: Ah, yes, this works now. I would add, though, that the $Q \cap S = \emptyset$ condition is really pointless. Yes, it causes the ideal to be not the whole ring (I think), but that's not necessary for its radicality.

Comment: thank you for answering. but may i ask what's wrong about letting $QR_S=R_S$ be the whole ring?

Comment: Nothing is wrong about this. Whoever posed the problem wanted to avoid the case for some nebulous reason.

Comment: $a^n/s^n=b/t\Rightarrow  a^nt=bs^n$: this is not quite right.

Comment: Oh right. Should instead be $w\left(a^nt-bs^n\right) = 0$ for some $w \in S$. Then we get $wa^nt = wbs^n \in Q$, thus $\left(wat\right)^t = wa^nt \cdot w^{n-1}t^{n-1} \in Q$ and thus $wat\in Q$ due to the assumption that $Q$ be radical. And with both $w$ and $t$ becoming invertible in $R_S$ (since they lie in $S$), this finishes the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with or without resorting to elements. We outline how to do this with the structure of ideals.

We have $Q$ is radical iff $Q=\bigcap\{P\ |\ Q\subseteq P,\ P\text{ is a prime ideal in }R\}$.  An ideal in $R_S$ is prime iff is of the form $PR_S$ for prime ideal $P$ in $R$ such that $P\cap S=\emptyset$.  Since $Q\cap S=\emptyset$, the extended ideal $QR_S$ is proper and thus contained in a maximal ideal. Localization preserves the lattice structure of the ideals which are disjoint from $S$, hence $QR_S$ is the intersection of the primes in $R_S$ containing it, i.e., it is a radical ideal.

I prefer this approach since it is conceptual rather than computational intensive.

Comment: thank you for answring, can you give some reference about your statement: and ideal in $R_S$ is prime iff is of the form $PR_S$ for prime ideal $P$ in $R$ such that $P∩S=∅$ as well? I don't think we have learnt that.

Comment: Any standard algebra text should have a proof of this. The way I remember it is by visualizing localization $\phi\colon R\to R_S.\ r\mapsto r/1$ as preserving the ideal lattice structure of those ideals disjoint to the multiplicative set. Then since prime ideals are equivalent to ring morphisms $f\colon R_S\to D$ with codomain an integral domain $D$, we have $ker(f\phi)R_S=\ker(f)$ showing us that prime ideals in $R_S$ come from prime ideals in $R$. The converse can be shown similarly